# GORM composite key based on start and end dates

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, relationship, composite-key

I want to have a table, where I want to have entries, which are date ranged.
How I normally did it, was to have a table with:
someId [not unique]
startDate
endDate

These three would create a primary key + I would add few constraints to make sure dates don't overlap etc.

Everything is fine from the database point of view, however when I want to create a domain class in Grails to handle it... well it's more difficult then I thought.
Is there a way, to make sure that if I have a relation:
ClassA hasOne ClassB [ClassB would be date ranged]
and I have entries in ClassB:

```
Id  StartDate  EndDate     Name
1   2011-11-01 2011-11-05  A
1   2011-11-06 2011-11-10  B
```

and assign objectB with name A to objectA on 2011-11-03 and then retrieve objectA on 2011-11-07 it will point to objectB with name B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we did in the end was:
create index and constraint on the three columns [on the database, since creating indexes in Grails 1.3.7 is broken and constraint handling is insane], created static `startDate` and `endDate` variables which hold start and end date of the current range. This way we were able to maintain the functionality we wanted and it performs really well.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a poor way to design your database.  In most cases, you really should just use a single numeric ID for objects.

If you are dealing with a situation where you have multiple date ranges associated with the same object, then you should structure your data to represent that, by having a parent object, and a child object that represents the list of date ranges.

```
class Foo {
    static hasMany = [bars:Bar]
    static mapping = {
        bars lazy:false
    }
    ...
}

class Bar {
    static belongsTo = [foo:Foo]
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    ...
}
```

Grails makes it really simple to have cascade deletes, so there's no real reason not to create it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not a solution. I would still have to do a search every time I want to access the data. I cannot use a simple findBy... since between won't work in my case, I have to do a criteria search query OR I would have to first find Foo and then look for Bar. In my experience composite key was always faster than multiple selects over multiple tables [or joining two tables].